# .NET Core: Случай получения значения поля из свойства

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Работая с `ASP.NET Core Identity`, я очередной раз заглянул в исходный код на [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) и увидел в классе `IdentityResult` следующие строки:

```
public class IdentityResult
    {
        private List<IdentityError> _errors = new List<IdentityError>();
        ...

        public IEnumerable<IdentityError> Errors => _errors;
        ...
    }
```

Конечно, наверное это сильно выдернуто из контекста, но тем не менее мне не понятно, зачем было создавать отдельное поле `_errors`, а потом чтобы получить его значение отдельно создавать свойство `Errors` *(да, если я не ошибаюсь это именно свойство, а не метод)* вместо того, чтобы просто написать:

```
public List<IdentityError> Errors { get; } = new List<IdentityError>();
```

Я бы понял если бы это был какой-то легаси код, но как никак `.NET Core`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смысл такого разделения - в том, что наружу отдается только возможность перечисления списка, но не его модификация.

В вашем же варианте внешний по отношению к классу код сможет менять список ошибок.

Comment: @maxwell В своем теле класс `IdentityResult`, только однажды использует (инициализирует) поле `_errors` - в методе `Failed(params IdentityError[] errors)`. В таком случае, разве нельзя было написать следующее: объявить свойство `IEnumerable<IdentityError> Errors { get; }` и в том же методе `Failed()` сделать: `Errors = new List<IdentityError>(errors)`

Comment: @adamshakhabov можно. Но тут, видимо, решили сделать чуть иначе.

Comment: Хм... а если кто-то решит в явную преобразовать этот тип в `List<IdentityError>`?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, дело в том что, как сказал автор, то что вернет `Errors` изменить нельзя. Да в __клиентском__ коде можно произвести `ToList()` на полученный перечислитель, но это уже будет создание __новой__ коллекции, типа клон.

Comment: @adamshakhabov Я имею ввиду не `.ToList()` а `(List<IdentityError>)Errors;`.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, да ты прав - только что посмотрел. __Приведение изменяет исходную коллекцию__. Теперь вообще ничего не понимаю)

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин то этот кто-то будет ССЗБ. Если сторонний код возвращает `IEnumerable<IdentityError>` - это означает что он может вернуть любой класс который реализует `IEnumerable<IdentityError>`. Приведение к списку - грязный хак, который делает код хрупким.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Если уж писать более надёжный код, то нужно выставлять readonly-обёртку. Обычно так и дел. (Нет, защищаться от рефлексии и unsafe я не планирую.)

Comment: @VladD ну, в данном случае IdentityResult - это временный объект, который передает данные от класса A до класса B. Иммутабельность для него - вопрос стиля а не архитектуры.

Comment: @VladD ты имеешь ввиду использовать IReadOnlyCollection?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, ну вообще-то да, если уж делать readonly-коллекцию, то неплохо бы и элементы коллекции тоже. Согласен.

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Ну да, используя метод [`List.AsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx), например. Но как правильно говорит Pavel Mayorov, если уж не доверять клиентам и делать список иммутабельным, то надо и элементы списка делать такими же.

Answer (score 8):

> вместо того, чтобы просто написать:
>
> `public List<IdentityError> Errors { get; } = new  List<IdentityError>();`

Тогда извне будут доступны методы интерфейса [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx), которые изменяют коллекцию: `Clear`, `Add`, `Remove`.

Видимо автор кода не хотел, чтобы кто-то мог вносить изменения, поэтому коллекцию `Errors` сделали доступным только для перечисления через интерфейс [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), который не содержит методов способных внести изменения.

Comment: Как выше указал @ДмитрийПолянин, клиентский код может использовать приведение и с легкостью изменять исходную коллекцию. Что в таком случае?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, Ну, ничего) Автор кода явно указывает, что этого делать не нужно не предоставляя методы для изменения коллекции. Одно дело когда методы доступны, вы ими пользуетесь и возникает баг, то тогда проблема у автора кода. И совсем другое дело, когда архитектура кода не предполагает доступ к этим методам, но вы ими пользуетесь через обходные пути и возникает баг. В таком случае проблема у вас.

Answer (score 1):

Определил два преимущества, который используется в фреймворках.

ваш пример:

```
// конкретный: структура данных List
1. "private" List<IdentityError> _errors = new List<IdentityError>();
// абстрактный контракт - перечисление (base contract)
2. "public" IEnumerable<IdentityError> Errors => _errors;
```

- Смотрите на модификатор доступа то есть **конкретный** тип **(1)** `private`.
  Ну **абстрактный** контракт **(2)** `public`.
  это является локализация для дальнейшей изменения чтобы не влиять другим модулем.
  То есть мы можем `List<T>` изменить на `Stack<T>` это не будет влиять на другим клиентам то есть изменения локализован (здесь и подразумевается слабая связанность (то есть автор гарантирует)).
- Здесь нарушается сокрытие информации потому что возвращает структуру данных.И поэтому он использует тип перечисление `IEnumerable<T>` чтобы сокрыть внутренние данные , чтобы **клиент не манипулировал** `Remove` , `Update` , `Add`. То есть можно было использовать **клонирование** но это **дорогостоящая операция** (оперативная память и так далее) поэтому здесь **использовано сокрытие информации (высокоуровневый,абстрактный интерфейс перечисление)** `IEnumerable<T>` (доступ только для перечисления).

P.S **Localization :** Когда будет изменение изменение будет в одном месте или изменение будет минимизирован.

Comment: достойный ответ.